# Read Json/Array string in Php

Tags: php, arrays, json, indexing

I have a string which is in valid Json format and it looks like this:

```
{
    "message": "success",
    "result": {
        "46620": {
            "course_id": "29",
            "en_title": "Google Analytics (Basic)",
            "fa_title": "Ù…Ø¨Ø§Ù†ÛŒ Ú¯ÙˆÚ¯Ù„ Ø¢Ù†Ø§Ù„ÛŒØªÛŒÚ©Ø²",
            "badge_link": "http://www.darsnameh.com/badge/index.php?user=46620&badge="
        },
        "49449": {
            "course_id": "16",
            "en_title": "Multimedia Reporting 1- Reporting in the Internet Age",
            "fa_title": "Ú¯Ø²Ø§Ø±Ø´â€ŒÚ¯Ø±ÛŒ Ú†Ù†Ø¯Ø±Ø³Ø§Ù†Ù‡â€ŒØ§ÛŒ Û±- Ú¯Ø²Ø§Ø±Ø´Ú¯Ø±ÛŒ Ø¯Ø± Ø²Ù…Ø§Ù†Ù‡â€ŒÛŒ Ø§ÙŠÙ†ØªØ±Ù†Øª",
            "badge_link": "http://www.darsnameh.com/badge/index.php?user=49449&badge="
        },
        "55480": {
            "course_id": "33",
            "en_title": "HTML for Journalists and Bloggers",
            "fa_title": "Ø¢Ø´Ù†Ø§ÛŒÛŒ Ø¨Ø§ Ø§Ú†â€ŒØªÛŒâ€ŒØ§Ù…â€ŒØ§Ù„ Ùˆ ÙÙ†Ø§ÙˆØ±ÛŒâ€ŒÙ‡Ø§ÛŒ Ø§ÛŒÙ†ØªØ±Ù†Øª Ø¨Ø±Ø§ÛŒ Ø±ÙˆØ²Ù†Ø§Ù…Ù‡â€ŒÙ†Ú¯Ø§Ø±Ø§Ù† Ùˆ ÙˆØ¨Ù„Ø§Ú¯â€ŒÙ†ÙˆÛŒØ³â€ŒÙ‡Ø§",
            "badge_link": "http://www.darsnameh.com/badge/index.php?user=55480&badge="
        },
        "59250": {
            "course_id": "31",
            "en_title": "Twitter",
            "fa_title": "ØªÙˆÛŒÛŒØªØ±",
            "badge_link": "http://www.darsnameh.com/badge/index.php?user=59250&badge="
        },
        "103716": {
            "course_id": "42",
            "en_title": "How to write a CV?",
            "fa_title": "Ú†Ú¯ÙˆÙ†Ù‡ Ø±Ø²ÙˆÙ…Ù‡ Ø¨Ù†ÙˆÛŒØ³ÛŒÙ…ØŸ",
            "badge_link": "http://www.darsnameh.com/badge/index.php?user=103716&badge="
        }
    }
}
```

I want to read different fields, for example all fa_titles, I use $obj = json_decode($str, true); to convert this to Json, then echo sizeof($obj['result']); shows me that it has 5 result object, but how can I access to fa_title or en_title fields now?

Comment: Use a [`foreach`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) loop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In JSON, arrays are designated by brackets (`[` and `]`) while dictionaries only have braces (`{` and `}`).

You could access each result object individually by doing `$obj['result']['46620']['en_title']`.
The result object is an associative array (also known as a dictionary) of associative arrays.

You can also iterate through each object using a `foreach` loop, as demonstrated in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26007/iterating-over-a-complex-associative-array-in-php)

Answer (score 3):

To loop through all the results, something like this should do it:

```
$obj = json_decode($str);
foreach ($obj->result as $result)
{
    $fa_title = $result->fa_title;
    $en_title = $result->en_title;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you can access as an array like that if you use the second parameter of json_decode as true