# Write serialized multidimensional array values to file with key path

Tags: php, arrays, serialization, iterator

My question is how can I successfully crawl all levels of this serialized data and write each leaf level to separate strings in a file, where each line contains the array "key path" and the value.
Basically, I need each value wrapped in a i18n function for translation purposes.

I have some serialized data in a mySQL database, here's a sample of a problematic value:

```
stdClass Object
(
 {...}
 [fields] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
            {...}
            [choices] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                            (
                                [text] => My string
                                [value] => 7
                                [isSelected] => 
                                [price] => 
                            )
     ) {...}
```

The expected result is each leaf value written to a PHP file with it's key hierearchy like this, so I can then reconvert it to an array:

```
$form['fields'][0]['choices'][0]['text'] = __( "My string", "tjxgallery" );
```

And here is my code that attempts to do that

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator( new RecursiveArrayIterator( $form_fields ) );

$strings_to_translate = array(
    '<?php' . PHP_EOL
);

foreach ( $iterator as $key => $value ) {

    // Fields to skip, as they don't contain any translatable strings
    $unwanted_fields = array(
        'inputName',
        'type',
        'size',
        'inputType',
        'descriptionPlacement',
        'postCustomFieldName',
        'allowedExtensions',
        'actionType',
        'operator',
        'logicType',
        'conditionalLogic',
    );

    // Only proceed if array item is a string and it's not empty and it's not a number and it's not in the ignored fields
    if ( ! in_array( $key, $unwanted_fields ) && ( is_string( $value ) && ( 0 < strlen( $value ) ) &&  ! is_numeric( $value ) ) ) {

        // Iterate through the sub arrays
        for ( $i = $iterator->getDepth() - 1; $i >= 0; $i -- ) {

            $path = '';

            // get the parent key of current item
            $subkey = $iterator->getSubIterator( $i )->key();

            // Build a string with the full key path - e.g. [0]['choices'][0]['text']
            if ( is_numeric( $subkey ) ) {

                if ( empty( $path ) ) {

                    $path = '[' . $subkey . '][\'' . $key;

                } else {

                    $path = '[' . $subkey . ']' . $key;

                }

            } else {

                if ( empty( $path ) ) {

                    $path = '[\'' . $subkey . '\'][\'' . $key;

                } else {

                    $path = '[\'' . $subkey . '\']' . $key;

                }

            }

        }

        // Build an array of translation ready strings e.g. $form['fields'][0]['text'] = __( "Give Up Clothes For Good – Cancer Research UK", "tjxgallery" );
        $strings_to_translate[] = '$form[\'fields\']' . $path . '\'] = __( "' . preg_replace( "/\n/", '', $value ) . '", "tjxgallery" );' . PHP_EOL;

    }
```

The result I get now is this:
    $form['fields'][0]['text'] = __( "My string", "tjxgallery" );

So , it's missing the `['choices'][0]` part.

Any help appreciated

thanks for your time

Comment: Are you looking to create `$path` each time or to append text to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added echo statements all over the place in your code to track down where the problem was occurring. I think there were two issues: one, `$path` is in an inner loop and keeps getting reset, and two, `$path` was being replaced each time, rather than having text appended to it.

This is what worked for me:

```
foreach ( $iterator as $key => $value ) {

    // Fields to skip, as they don't contain any translatable strings
    $unwanted_fields = array(
        ...
    );
    // Only proceed if array item is a string and it's not empty
    // and it's not a number and it's not in the ignored fields
    if ( ! in_array( $key, $unwanted_fields ) && ( is_string( $value ) && ( 0 < strlen( $value ) ) &&  ! is_numeric( $value ) ) ) {

        // start a new path from $key here.
        $path = '';

        // Iterate through the sub arrays
        for ( $i = $iterator->getDepth() - 1; $i >= 0; $i -- ) {

            // get the parent key of current item
            $subkey = $iterator->getSubIterator( $i )->key();
            // Build a string with the full key path - e.g. [0]['choices'][0]['text']
            $path .= '[\'' . $subkey . '\']';
        }
        // OK, we've constructed the path. Add $key to the end.
        $path .= '[\'' . $key . '\']';

        // Build an array of translation ready strings e.g. $form['fields'][0]['text'] = __( "Give Up Clothes For Good – Cancer Research UK", "tjxgallery" );
        echo '$form[\'fields\']' . $path . ' = __( "' . preg_replace( "/\n/", '', $value ) . '", "tjxgallery" );' . "\n";

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted reply gets me most of the way, but I still needed to check if a key is numeric because it has to be `[0]` not `['0']`

Also, still need to figure out why the keys are not in the correct order:

```
$form['fields'][0]['choices'][0]['text'] = __( "String 1", "tjxgallery" );
$form['fields'][1]['choices'][0]['text'] = __( "String 2", "tjxgallery" );
$form['fields'][2]['choices'][0]['text'] = __( "String 3", "tjxgallery" );
$form['fields'][3]['choices'][0]['text'] = __( "String 4", "tjxgallery" );
```

should be ( note the numeric keys are swapped:

```
$form['fields'][0]['choices'][0]['text'] = __( "String 1", "tjxgallery" );
$form['fields'][0]['choices'][1]['text'] = __( "String 2", "tjxgallery" );
$form['fields'][0]['choices'][2]['text'] = __( "String 3", "tjxgallery" );
$form['fields'][0]['choices'][3]['text'] = __( "String 4", "tjxgallery" );
```

Here is what needs to be changed:

```
if ( is_numeric( $subkey ) ) {
    $path = '[' . $subkey . ']' . $path;
} else {
    $path =  '[\'' . $subkey . '\']' . $path;
}
```

So adding the keys in reverse.