# PHP associate array

Tags: php

I have a output of print_r below and I want to access all the individual elements value with foreach loop but unfortunately I am unable to do that via foreach. Could anyone please help me with the associate array question.
I can access via this `$arr['Level1'][Date]` and it returns value as "2015-04-14 07:15".

But how to get all the element values via foreach loop?

```
Array
(
    [Level1] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2015-04-14 07:15
            [img1] => pic1
            [img2] => pic2
            [InnerLevel] => Array
                (
                    [0] => value1
                    [1] => value2
                )

        )


    [Level2] => Array
        (
            [Date] => 2015-04-15 08:15
            [img1] => pic1
            [img2] => pic2
            [InnerLevel] => Array
                (
                    [0] => value3
                    [1] => value4
                )

        )

)
```

Comment: whats the exact output your after?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php
foreach ($myarray as $level => $itemArr) {

    if(is_array($itemArr)) {
        foreach ($itemArr as $levelArr) {
            if(is_array($levelArr)) {
                foreach ($levelArr as $key => $interlevelValue) {
                    echo $interlevelValue;
                }
            } else {
            echo $levelArr;
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo $itemArr;
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($myarray as $item) {
    echo $item['Date'] . "\n";
}
```

The fact that the array is associative or not doesn't change anything.

`$item` is successively a copy of `$myarray['Level1']` then `$myarray['Level2']` (etc. if more) in the foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you Casimir!
but "Level1" and "Level2" above are also dynamic value so i cannot say $myarray['Level1'].
also there could be more level(1...n)?

Comment: @newbie83: it's not a problem, this way ignore totally what are the item "names" ("keys" is the good term), but if you want to know that, use `foreach ($myarray as $key=>$item)` instead, where `$key` contains the key name (so `Level1` for example).

Answer (score 0):

It depends on index depth.

To extract simple associative arrays like:

```
$mainarray['Name']='Value';
```

Use:

```
foreach ($mainarray as $aname=>$avalue)
{
    echo $aname." in ".$mainarray." = ".$avalue." <br>";
}
```

To extract deeper associative arrays like:

```
$mainarray['Child']['Name']='Value';
```

Use:

```
foreach ($mainarray as $aname=>$asubarray)
{
    echo "In ".$aname." from ".$mainarray."...<br>";
    foreach ($asubarray as $asubname=>$asubvalue){
        echo $asubname." = ".$avalue." <br>";
    }
    echo "<br>";
}
```

This:

```
<br>
```

represents new line. If you're running the code from a command line or you just want text only output, then use this for a new line:

```
\n
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is another way of doing this in php.

"Iterating over Multidimensional arrays is easy with Spl Iterators :

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator($array));

foreach($iterator as $key=>$value) {
    echo $key.' -- '.$value.'<br />';
}
```

This will iterate through all possible iterable objects.
See

- http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php
- http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-SPL.html

" - Quoted from - https://stackoverflow.com/a/2149106/1766122 answered by @Gordon